# How to collapse all classes outlining in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>** works really great to collapse all methods in a class however I have a hard time finding a way to collapse all classes outlining in the whole file.

One may ask - why do you have many classes in one file ? It's because I'm using MSpec and classes are my tests so I have files with tens of classes. In order to wrap my head around what is going on I often have to collapse classes one by one but that is not really efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help much but you can use Ctrl+M+M to toggle the collapse of a class to its definition.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but it only collapses one current class, bit helpful but still doing it for like 30 classes is painful :-)

Comment: Why not collapse all with Ctrl + M, Ctrl + O and then manually expand to what you are interested in?

Comment: @bubblez The issue is that if you have many classes in a file (a legitimate case when working with unit test frameworks like MSpec), collapsing via Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O only collapses the class you are in. You have to Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O in every single class, one at a time.

Comment: Jay gave a right answer - you can collapse all outlining by using Ctrl + M, Ctrl + L

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Ha -- well, apparently I just needed to offer a bounty before I would discover an answer minutes later.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will toggle all outlining. If anything in the file is collapsed, the first time you invoke this will expand everything and *then* invoking it again will collapse everything. This also collapses the namespace, which is a small inconvenience, but I'll call it progress.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: damn, can't believe i missed out on this bounty, i use `Ctrl+M`, `Ctrl+L` all the time :)

Comment: Also Ctrl+A, Ctrl+M-M works for me, also collapses the name space.

Comment: Ah ha! Happy to click once to expand the namespace... whew. What a time saver.

Answer (score 32):

The accepted answer is the roundabout way of doing it.

You're looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, which collapses all.

As [Jay mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229812/84873), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> expands all, but collapses all if already expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found it more convenient to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> **and specify the range**:

- To collapse everything in a file I press: ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.
- To collapse only a few sections I press: ***<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>***/***<kbd>PgDn</kbd>*** or ***<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>MouseClick</kbd>*** then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

**This will toggle** just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> **but you decide the range!**

It comes in handy to collapse multiple object initializers within a single method / everything before and after the working area. Also to expand a few relevant full-property / region / function / foreach.